# How to store all lightning input values in object type attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

My requirement is to override the standard new button which creates a record of the `Employee__c` object.

I have designed the UI with the help of the Aura component but I am stuck while saving the record
because in the Employee__c object, there are 45 fields.

So if I used like below code then I have to set a number of parameters so this is not a good process.

```
var Name=component.find("name_1").get("v.value"); 
action.setParams({
    Name:Name, 
})
```

so I have used the second approach that is create an object-type attribute to store all the input type values.
like this-

```
<aura:attribute  name="EmployeeObj" type="object"/>

<lightning:input  type="text" aura:id="Emp_name" label="Employee Name" value="{!v.EmployeeObj.Name}"/>
```

but it gives me an error when I type any letter in the field that is-
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Name')**

```
JS Code--->
 SaveEmployeeRecord: function(component,event,helper){
    console.log("save Button Is click");
    var RecordData=component.get("v.EmployeeObj");
    console.log('RecordData',RecordData);   
}
```

So can you please help me to figure out the problem or if you have another approach to save the record so let me know.

Thank you

Comment: I tried your code, it works without adding default attribute. The error appears to be in JS and not in markup. You can add JS to this answer.

Comment: I have added the JS code in the question please check.

Comment: Strange , it's working for me even if you use API name of object instead of "object". Adding or removing default is not having any difference either.

Comment: can you please share your code if you don't have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @amitghadage for pointing in the right direction.
The error in question is not something which will be dependent on `default` attribute.

Here's a working code which will ensure binding & saving multiple fields in Aura.

Markup : We need specify the default object type and it's fields for binding using `lightning:input` as below.

```
 <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<!-- Specify default values for all fields -->      
<aura:attribute  name="EmployeeObj" type="Employee__c" default="{'sobjectType':'Employee__c','Name':''}"/>
      <lightning:input  type="text" aura:id="Emp_name" label="Employee Name" value="{!v.EmployeeObj.Name}"/>
    
      <lightning:button label="Neutral" title="Neutral action" onclick="{! c.saveRec }"/>

</aura:component>
```

JS Controller : Since we get proxy object, use JSON methods to check actual values.

```
({
    saveRec: function(component,event,helper){
      console.log("save Button Is click");
      var RecordData=component.get("v.EmployeeObj");
      console.log('RecordData',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(RecordData)));

// Stringify the JS object and then pass it to Apex for DML. 

  }
})
```

I would recommend you to use `lightning:recordEditForm` instead.
More info : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation

Comment: should I have to give all 45 field names in default?

Comment: Yes , try with a few and check your use case. Then add all. But why do you require all 45 fields editable on one form? Maybe that question is out of scope on this forum.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Rohit !!

Comment: Your code is helpful for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Set default value for EmployeeObj. Here when page loads EmployeeObj is undefined hence you are facing this issue.

```
<aura:attribute  name="EmployeeObj" type="object" default="{'Employee__c': 'Case','Name': ''}"/>

<lightning:input  type="text" aura:id="Emp_name" label="Employee Name" value="{!v.EmployeeObj.Name}"/>
```

Comment: should I have to give default key-value pairs like this?

default="{'name': ' '}"